# Является ли здесь "по разным оценкам" вводным выражением?

Tags: пунктуация

По разным оценкам около 25 % дорогостоящего конденсата не возвращается обратно в энергетический цикл.

Comment: Мне кажется не совсем точным выражение "по разным оценкам", поскольку приводится одна величина, а не диапазон её значений. Это одна и та же оценка, которая при обращении к разным источникам оказалась такой,  какая приведена. Я бы сказал "по  данным из (или по оценкам) разных источников".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном предложение нераспространенное сочетание не является вводным словом, оно входит в основное сообщение и по смыслу, и по структуре предложения.

Однако при распространении оборота обособление возможно: По  оценкам различных источников, около 25 % дорогостоящего конденсата не возвращается обратно в энергетический цикл.

Answer (score 2):

> Является ли здесь “по разным оценкам” вводным выражением?

По-моему, ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ.

ПРИМЕРЫ см. в **Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений"**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюс см. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%CF%EE+%F0%E0%E7%ED%FB%EC+%EE%F6%E5%ED%EA%E0%EC :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё зависит от структуры предложения. Обособление этого сочетания может быть обязательным, невозможным или авторским.  Береговая линия Чукотского полуострова молода, по разным оценкам ей от 10 до 40 тысяч лет. Много встречается примеров без обособления. Обособить - это не означает только указать источник сообщения. Обособить - это выделить с какой-то авторской целью (подчеркнуть/актуализировать или, наоборот, сделать добавочным замечанием).